# Passing xvalue of std::string to function taking std::string_view

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

Is it UB to do the following?

```
void foo(std::string_view view) {...}

void bar()
{
   std::string str;
   foo(std::move(str));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure it just doesn't compile.

Comment: @nwp, I would try before being pretty sure. It compiles just because string_view has the ctor taking const string&

Comment: What exactly do you think would make this UB?  `string_view` is read only and `move` doesn't actually move anything.  It is just a cast.

Comment: @Bikineev: "*string_view has the ctor taking const string&*" No, it does not. Many non-standard implementations of it does, but the actual C++17 `basic_string_view` doesn't work that way. The conversion happens because `basic_string` converts itself to a `basic_string_view`; the view class is considered the more basic of the two.

Comment: This question is more interesting if you ask about prvalues in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is well-defined behavior, though it is not particularly useful. `basic_string`'s `operator basic_string_view` will be used to perform the conversion, and it has no lvalue/rvalue restrictions. So it'll do the same thing it would have if you hadn't used `move` at all.